# MySQL 5.6 not starting in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-workbench, ubuntu-16.04

I am unable to start the MySQL server. In the "StartUp/Stutdown" page of MySQL Workbench, initially Start Server button is enabled. When i click on it, a pop up with the following error is seen, "Unhandled exception: TextBox_append_text_with_encoding() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)".

Comment: That unhandled exception is just a side effect of the start/stop problem and can be safely ignored here.

Answer (score 0):

It is a post installation/upgrade issue.

Its a known bug reported at https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85807

You can temporarily use solution provided at https://askubuntu.com/a/762775/458468